# getting 'Unauthorized' when testing kubernetes api-server

Tags: kubernetes, coreos, kubectl, kubelet

I have Container Linux by CoreOS alpha (1284.2.0) and I try to install kubernetes 1.5.2 on.

I notice that the `kube-proxy` pod fails and I searched and I noticed that the `api-server` manifest might not be configured properly.

I configured `kubectl` on my mac pro desktop using the documentation at https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/configure-kubectl.html

when I execute `kubectl get nodes` I get `error: You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials)`.

so I try testing with curl. the server's hostname is `coreos-2.tux-in.com`.

```
ufk-osx-music:~ ufk$ curl http://coreos-2.tux-in.com:8080
curl: (7) Failed to connect to coreos-2.tux-in.com port 8080: Connection refused
ufk-osx-music:~ ufk$ curl https://coreos-2.tux-in.com
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: Invalid certificate chain
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
ufk-osx-music:~ ufk$ curl --insecure https://coreos-2.tux-in.com
Unauthorized
```

this is my `kube-apiserver.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: kube-apiserver
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  hostNetwork: true
  containers:
  - name: kube-apiserver
    image: quay.io/coreos/hyperkube:v1.5.2_coreos.0
    command:
    - /hyperkube
    - apiserver
    - --bind-address=0.0.0.0
    - --etcd-servers=http://127.0.0.1:4001
    - --allow-privileged=true
    - --service-cluster-ip-range=10.3.0.0/24
    - --secure-port=443
    - --advertise-address=10.79.218.2
    - --admission-

    control=NamespaceLifecycle,LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,DefaultStorageClass,ResourceQuota
        - --tls-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver.pem
        - --tls-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver-key.pem
        - --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca.pem
        - --service-account-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver-key.pem
        - --runtime-config=extensions/v1beta1/networkpolicies=true
        - --anonymous-auth=false
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            host: 127.0.0.1
            port: 8080
            path: /healthz
          initialDelaySeconds: 15
          timeoutSeconds: 15
        ports:
        - containerPort: 443
          hostPort: 443
          name: https
        - containerPort: 8080
          hostPort: 8080
          name: local
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/ssl
          name: ssl-certs-kubernetes
          readOnly: true
        - mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs
          name: ssl-certs-host
          readOnly: true
      volumes:
      - hostPath:
          path: /etc/kubernetes/ssl
        name: ssl-certs-kubernetes
      - hostPath:
          path: /usr/share/ca-certificates
        name: ssl-certs-host
```

and this is my `kube-proxy.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: kube-proxy
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  hostNetwork: true
  containers:
  - name: kube-proxy
    image: quay.io/coreos/hyperkube:v1.5.2_coreos.0
    command:
    - /hyperkube
    - proxy
    - --master=http://127.0.0.1:8080
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs
      name: ssl-certs-host
      readOnly: true
  volumes:
  - hostPath:
      path: /usr/share/ca-certificates
    name: ssl-certs-host
```

and this is the controller's kubeconfig file `controler-kubeconfig.yaml`:

```
current-context: tuxin-coreos-context
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    server: http://127.0.0.1:8080
  name: tuxin-coreos-cluster
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: tuxin-coreos-cluster
  name: tuxin-coreos-context
kind: Config
preferences:
  colors: true
users:
- name: kubelet
  user:
    client-certificate: /etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver.pem
    client-key: /etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver-key.pem
```

any information regarding the issue would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welp in general I wasn't using the proper credentials in `.kube/config` file. and I also wasn't using the same name of cluster and context that I typed in the controller's kubeconfig.

this is the working `.kube/config` file:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: /Users/ufk/Projects/tuxin-coreos/kubernetes/certs/ca.pem
    server: https://coreos-2.tux-in.com
  name: tuxin-coreos-cluster
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: tuxin-coreos-cluster
    user: default-admin
  name: tuxin-coreos-context
current-context: tuxin-coreos-context
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: default-admin
  user:
    username: kubelet
    client-certificate: /Users/ufk/Projects/tuxin-coreos/kubernetes/certs/client.pem
    client-key: /Users/ufk/Projects/tuxin-coreos/kubernetes/certs/client-key.pem
```

my controller's kubeconfig:

```
current-context: tuxin-coreos-context
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    server: http://127.0.0.1:8080
  name: tuxin-coreos-cluster
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: tuxin-coreos-cluster
  name: tuxin-coreos-context
kind: Config
preferences:
  colors: true
users:
- name: kubelet
  user:
    client-certificate: /etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver.pem
    client-key: /etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver-key.pem
```